# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'StatusChange' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am designing web application when I click save it shows the error Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'StatusChange' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.please anyone help me to fix this. Below is the code for status change.

Comment: Perhaps showing us the code for saving instead of loading data would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi I have updated SQL kindly check

Comment: You're missing all of the code we can use to help. The error is because your code is trying to insert an explicit value into a column that is an `identity` column. An `identity` column generates it's own values so it won't let you insert values into them. Somewhere in the code (you have not posted), you are trying to insert a value into it. The column is probably `RegistrationID`. You need to 1. Work out which column is the identity column in the table; 2. Post the code that is actually inserting.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework and LINQ or are you just throwing SQL strings at the database. Find the ASP code that has a SQL string with an INSERT in it and post it

Comment: Hi Nick what code you want to help me

Comment: OK so we have established that the identity column is `ID`. The web code you have posted is `SELECT`. We need `INSERT` or if it is in LINQ we need the LINQ code.

Comment: Hi Nick I have changed the code now doesn't show any error but not saving in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check table identity before to save as below

```
select is_identity from sys.columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[StatusChange]', 'U') and name = 'column_Name'
```

Comment: Hi Anjan when I ececute the above query the column is blank doesn't have any value what to add to fix my bug?

Comment: You can set on identity seed of the table in database. here is code SET IDENTITY_INSERT StatusChange ON , here is more concept https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Comment: one more link which explaining http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-insert-values-into-an-identity-column-in-sql-server

Comment: write this sql statement directly in query analyzer to set on identity seed ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StatusChange]
  ADD TableID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

Comment: Hi what you said its already there in table do you want me to change anything

Comment: yes, can you check identity see is on or not if not then on it.