# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Garancija' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating Edit HTTP Post Action Method and when I press Edit button I get error

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Garancija' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

When I check table `[dbo].[Garancija]` I saw that Identity is ON

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Garancija] (
    [ProduzenaGarancijaID]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Broj_Police]           INT            NOT NULL,
    [GeneralniUgovor]       INT            NOT NULL,
    [ImeVlasnika]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Adresa_Ulica]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Adresa_Broj]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Adresa_PBroj]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Adresa_Mjesto]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [JMBG]                  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [VrsteVozilaID]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [MarkaVozilaID]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [ModelVozilaID]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [Sasija]                NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Snaga]                 NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Zapremina]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [VrstaMjenjacaID]       INT            NOT NULL,
    [Is4x4]                 BIT            NULL,
    [Predjeni_Kilometri]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Kupovna_Vrijednost]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Namjena]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [GorivoID]              INT            NOT NULL,
    [DatumPrveRegistracije] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DatumPrveProdaje]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DatumKupovineVozila]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DatumPocetkaGarancije] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DatumIstekaGarancije]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [TrajanjeGarancije]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [LimitPokrica]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [OgranicenjeKm]         FLOAT (53)     NULL,
    [ProduktID]             INT            NOT NULL,
    [ProgramPokrica]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [CjenovnikID]           INT            NOT NULL,
    [Cijena]                FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
    [DatumUnosta]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DatumPromjene]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [BrojPotvrde]           INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Garancija] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProduzenaGarancijaID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Garancija_VrsteMjenjaca_VrstaMjenjacaID] FOREIGN KEY ([VrstaMjenjacaID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[VrsteMjenjaca] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Garancija_VrsteVozila_VrsteVozilaID] FOREIGN KEY ([VrsteVozilaID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[VrsteVozila] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Garancija_Cjenovnik_CjenovnikID] FOREIGN KEY ([CjenovnikID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Cjenovnik] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Garancija_Gorivo_GorivoID] FOREIGN KEY ([GorivoID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Gorivo] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Garancija_MarkeVozila_MarkaVozilaID] FOREIGN KEY ([MarkaVozilaID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MarkeVozila] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Garancija_Modeli_ModelVozilaID] FOREIGN KEY ([ModelVozilaID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Modeli] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Garancija_Produkti_ProduktID] FOREIGN KEY ([ProduktID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Produkti] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

What I did so far is that I try to debug application but compiler is not enter into method

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TriglavOsiguranje.Data;
using TriglavOsiguranje.Models.ViewModels;
using TriglavOsiguranje.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Net;

namespace TriglavOsiguranje.Areas.Uposlenik.Controllers
{
    [Area("Uposlenik")]
    public class GarancijaController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;

        [BindProperty]
        public GarancijaViewModel GarancijaVM { get; set; }

        public GarancijaController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;

            GarancijaVM = new GarancijaViewModel()
            {
                Gorivo = _db.Gorivo.ToList(),
                Cijenovnik = _db.Cjenovnik.ToList(),
                MarkeVozila = _db.MarkeVozila.ToList(),
                ModeliVozila = _db.Modeli.ToList(),
                Produkt = _db.Produkti.ToList(),
                VrstaMjenjaca = _db.VrsteMjenjaca.ToList(),
                VrstaVozila = _db.VrsteVozila.ToList(),
                Garancija = new ProduzenaGarancija()
            };
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var garancija = _db.Garancija.Include(m => m.MarkaVozila).Include(m => m.ModelVozila).Include(m => m.VrsteVozila);
            return View(await garancija.ToListAsync());
        }

        //GET : Product Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(GarancijaVM);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePOST()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Garancija.Add(GarancijaVM.Garancija);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(GarancijaVM);
        }



        //GET Edit
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? Id)
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            GarancijaVM.Garancija = await _db.Garancija.Include(m => m.Gorivo)
                 .Include(m => m.MarkaVozila).Include(m => m.ModelVozila)
                .Include(m => m.Produkt).Include(m => m.VrstaMjenjaca)
                .Include(m => m.VrsteVozila).Include(m => m.Cjenovnik)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ProduzenaGarancijaID == Id);

            return GarancijaVM.Garancija == null ? NotFound() : (IActionResult)View(GarancijaVM);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, ProduzenaGarancija garancija)
        {
            if (id != garancija.ProduzenaGarancijaID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Update(garancija);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(garancija);
        }


        //GET: Details Garancija
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? Id)
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            GarancijaVM.Garancija = await _db.Garancija.Include(m => m.Gorivo)
                .Include(m => m.Gorivo).Include(m => m.MarkaVozila).Include(m => m.ModelVozila)
                .Include(m => m.Produkt).Include(m => m.VrstaMjenjaca).Include(m => m.VrsteVozila)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ProduzenaGarancijaID == Id);

            if (GarancijaVM.Garancija == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(GarancijaVM);
        }

        //GET: Delete GarancijaVM
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? Id)
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            GarancijaVM.Garancija = await _db.Garancija.Include(m => m.Gorivo)
                .Include(m => m.Gorivo).Include(m => m.MarkaVozila).Include(m => m.ModelVozila)
                .Include(m => m.Produkt).Include(m => m.VrstaMjenjaca).Include(m => m.VrsteVozila)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ProduzenaGarancijaID == Id);

            if (GarancijaVM.Garancija == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(GarancijaVM);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            ProduzenaGarancija produzena = await _db.Garancija.FindAsync(id);

            if (produzena == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                _db.Garancija.Remove(produzena);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second think which I did is in my model I am put propery but I doesnt fix the error

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Here is my Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TriglavOsiguranje.Models
{
    public class ProduzenaGarancija
    {
        /*Podaci o vlasniku*/
        [Key]    
        public int ProduzenaGarancijaID { get; set; }

        public int Broj_Police { get; set; }

        public int GeneralniUgovor { get; set; }

        public string ImeVlasnika { get; set; }

        public string Adresa_Ulica { get; set; }

        public string Adresa_Broj { get; set; }

        public string Adresa_PBroj { get; set; }

        public string Adresa_Mjesto { get; set; }

        public string JMBG { get; set; }

                 /* Podaci o vozilu */

        [Display(Name ="Vrste Vozila")]
        public int VrsteVozilaID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("VrsteVozilaID")]
        public virtual VrstaVozila VrsteVozila { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Marka vozila")]
        public int MarkaVozilaID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("MarkaVozilaID")]
        public virtual MarkeVozila MarkaVozila { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Model vozila")]
        public int ModelVozilaID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ModelVozilaID")]
        public virtual ModeliVozila ModelVozila { get; set; }

        public string Sasija { get; set; }

        public string Snaga { get; set; }

        public string Zapremina { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vrsta mjenjaca")]
        public int VrstaMjenjacaID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("VrstaMjenjacaID")]
        public virtual VrstaMjenjaca VrstaMjenjaca { get; set; }

        public bool Is4x4 { get; set; }

        public string Predjeni_Kilometri { get; set; }

        public string Kupovna_Vrijednost { get; set; }

        public string Namjena { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vrsta goriva")]
        public int GorivoID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GorivoID")]
        public virtual Gorivo Gorivo { get; set; }

        /* Podaci o garanciji */

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public string DatumPrveRegistracije { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public string DatumPrveProdaje { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public string DatumKupovineVozila { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public string DatumPocetkaGarancije { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public string DatumIstekaGarancije { get; set; }

        public string TrajanjeGarancije { get; set; }

        public string LimitPokrica { get; set; }

        public double OgranicenjeKm { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Produkt/Nacin prodaje")]
        public int ProduktID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProduktID")]
        public virtual Produkt Produkt { get; set; }

        public string ProgramPokrica { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Cjenovnik / Zapremina Vozila")]
        public int CjenovnikID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CjenovnikID")]
        public virtual Cjenovnik Cjenovnik { get; set; }

        public double Cijena { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public string DatumUnosta { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public string DatumPromjene { get; set; }

        public int BrojPotvrde { get; set; }


    }
}
```

I am also using VM to bind dropdown from db

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TriglavOsiguranje.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class GarancijaViewModel
    {
        public ProduzenaGarancija Garancija { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Cjenovnik> Cijenovnik { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Gorivo> Gorivo { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MarkeVozila> MarkeVozila { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ModeliVozila> ModeliVozila { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Produkt> Produkt { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<VrstaMjenjaca> VrstaMjenjaca { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<VrstaVozila> VrstaVozila { get; set; }




               }
}
```

I am also checked this link here

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357624/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-movies-when-identit)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617958/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-statuschange-when-id)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity)

I have no idea where this error comes from but I suppose its problem with database.
A couple of time I update-database and check Is Identity = true but doesnt solve my issue
Any suggestion or comment what could be problem ?

**EDIT**

```
Project.Areas.Uposlenik.Controllers.GarancijaController.Create(ProduzenaGarancija garancija) in GarancijaController.cs
-
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ProduzenaGarancija garancija)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Garancija.Add(garancija);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(garancija);
        }
```

Comment: Your edit is trying to set your table's `Garancija.ProduzenaGarancijaID` column to a certain value, but because that column is defined as an `identity` column, MSSQL doesn't allow you to do that.

Comment: Even If I disable Identity it's say that 

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProduzenaGarancijaID', table 'Triglav.dbo.Garancija'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
 The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When 'IDENTITY_INSERT' is set to 'OFF', we cannot explicitly insert data to identity column.

In order to insert data into identity column, we need to set 'IDENTITY_INSERT' to 'ON' for that table.

Also, while explicitly inserting data to identity column, we need to keep in mind that the column will be a `Primary Key` of the table as well.
Which means that neither `null` nor `duplicate` values will be allowed to be inserted explicitly to that column.

If working on Entity Framework, you can try these two options to explicitly insert data into identity column:

1. execute below code where you are calling `_db.Update(garancija)` in the `Edit` method

```
_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Garancija ON");
_db.Update(garancija);
_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Garancija OFF");
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

2. For the `Key` column i.e. `ProduzenaGarancijaID` in the model class, you can set the attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]    
public int ProduzenaGarancijaID { get; set; }
```

Comment: SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Garancija] ON 
You mean like this or .. ?

Comment: After I set this to ON again same problem

Comment: Again same error
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Garancija' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: did u update database after setting IDENTITY_INSERT to ON?

Comment: Sure, and also Add-Migration

Comment: edited my answer to provide some code which helps in inserting data explicitly to identity columns. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days checking hold application I notice error in my View

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-asp-route-id="@Model.Garancija.Id" value="Izmijeni" />
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success">Nazad</a>
        </div>
```

In some reason `asp-asp-route-id="@Model.Garancija.Id"` I dint check that I have double `asp-asp` that's why I get error
Thank you guys however ! ! !

Answer (score 0):

```
set identity_insert [tablename] on
insert into [tablename] (columnlist) values(valuelist)
set identity_insert [tablename] off
```

Comment: I have no idea is it good to delete table and create again. Will someting change ?? 
Exactly like this  try a couple of times and nothing happened

Comment: Are you creating this table with Code First?

Comment: Yes, I did using EF

Comment: The model looks good, and matches the table...very odd. Does the exception occur on this line: await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: Yes Exactly in _db.SaveChangesAsync();
I updated my question

Comment: Adding this "[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]" will make no difference....the [Key] attribute defaults to identitiy. It concerns me that the debugger does not jump into that code block...have you figured that out yet?

Comment: After adding this cople of code I get this error
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Garancija'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Garancija'. The duplicate key value is (0).
 The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I belive that GarancijaVM make problem, because I add VM for drop down, and In my form there are a couple of drop downs which most probably cause the error

Comment: This is a tough one...for some reason EF is not recognising that your table demands Identity. Maybe try rebuilding the table.